# Microsoft Bot Framework and Slack - always returning Forbidden when testing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bots, botframework, slack

I've registered a bot and write a demo with MS bot and LUIS.I also hosted it in azure  and got a https endpoint like

> https://$team***plus:t27oCcSM0b85uzQhl2bg2W****KQAbe8yyjojegY4HrMvs@teambotplus.******eweb****et/deploy , 
>   and I paste it like https://$team***plus:t27oCcSM0b85uzQhl2bg2W****KQAbe8yyjojegY4HrMvs@teambotplus.******eweb****et/deploy/api/messages

However,when typed the Test button ,I just got :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFu8W.png)

It's also added in slack channel,and returned nothing after I send a message.

Three messages from slack channel issues

*POST to luckybot failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 403
*There was an error sending this message to your bot: Forbidden
*There was an error sending this message to your bot: Forbidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The https endpoint should looks like https://YourWebAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/messages and that's the URL you should put in your Bot's configuration page.